# CodeIgniter - How to make function that extends helper?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, meta-tags

First my plan was to make a library that read php code content with html meta content and send it into html header.

And just several day ago, I found that CodeIgniter already working about meta tags and My plan change...

Now how to make my library extends this html helper like this

```
class Htmlplus extends CI_html {

    public function show(){
        //show html header
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the docs?

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html#extending-helpers

Or do you looking for some other solution?

*edit to comment #1*

using helper functions in an extended helper is same way as you would do anywhere else. just use them (make sure, helper is loaded)

e.g. in the file application/helpers/MY_url_helper.php you can use anchor()

```
function helper_test($str) {
    return anchor($str, 'test');
}
```

Comment: okay that docs do not explain how to access parent function. Such as: I am plan to using `"link_tag" with data load from pages.php` and/or `"meta" with data from same location`. How can I perform that things.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of CI and load helper!
    class Htmlplus extends CI_html {

```
    public function show(){
        //show html header
        $ci = & get_intance();
        $ci->load->helper('myhelper');
        myfunction();
    }

}
```